# How to stream 2 million rows from SQL Server without crashing Node?

Tags: sql-server, node.js, stream

I am using Node to copy 2 million rows from SQL Server to another database, so of course I use the "streaming" option, like this:

```
    const sql = require('mssql')
    ...
    const request = new sql.Request()
    request.stream = true
    request.query('select * from verylargetable')     
    request.on('row', row => {
        promise = write_to_other_database(row);
    })
```

My problem is that I have do an asynchronous operation with each row ( insert into another database), which takes time.

The reading is faster than the writing, so the "on row" events just keep coming, and memory eventually fills-up with pending promises, and eventually crashes Node.  This is frustrating -- the whole point of "streaming" is to avoid this, isn't it?

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is this a one time operation? If so, just use SSMS.

Comment: Just my opinion but it seems like Node isn't the right tool for this - why not simply use SSIS?

Comment: Link server, SSIS, OPENQUERY so many better choices for migrating 2 million rows than doing it with node.

Comment: The "other" database is Oracle, and this is not a one-time thing -- it has to be automated.

Comment: So you are querying 2 million rows then iterating over each of the 2 million rows to insert each one individually? Then you trigger 2 million "on row insert" events simultaneously and you expect the server to be able to handle this? Just making sure I understand the situation here.

Comment: No, I do not trigger any events.  I only respond to "row" events that are generated by the query.  The problem is that these row events arrive faster than I can process them.

Comment: Well Nick - I actually think you could make this work well with Node, but you need the right tool to work with asynchronous code. First - that streaming API seems really bad, as it doesn't support `pause` or `resume` so you can't control the flow - I'll check the code and come back...

...checked and it seems that you could use pipe and consume the stream, I'll write an answer here.

Answer (score 4):

### To stream millions of rows without crashing, intermittently [pause your request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#streaming).

```
sql.connect(config, err => {

    if (err) console.log(err);

    const request = new sql.Request();
    request.stream = true; // You can set streaming differently for each request
    request.query('select * from dbo.YourAmazingTable'); // or 
    request.execute(procedure)

    request.on('recordset', columns => {
        // Emitted once for each recordset in a query
        //console.log(columns);
    });

    let rowsToProcess = [];

    request.on('row', row => {
        // Emitted for each row in a recordset
        rowsToProcess.push(row);
        if (rowsToProcess.length >= 3) {
            request.pause();
            processRows();
          }
          console.log(row);
     });

    request.on('error', err => {
        // May be emitted multiple times
        console.log(err);
    });

    request.on('done', result => {
        // Always emitted as the last one
        processRows();
        //console.log(result);

    });

    const processRows = () => {
        // process rows
        rowsToProcess = [];
        request.resume();
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

The problems seems to be caused by reading the stream using "row" events that don't allow you to control the flow of the stream. This should be possible with "pipe" method, but then you end up in a Data Stream and implementing a writable stream - which may be tricky.

A simple solution would be to use [Scramjet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scramjet) so your code would be complete in a couple lines:

```
const sql = require('mssql')
const {DataStream} = require("scramjet");
//...

const request = new sql.Request()
request.stream = true
request.query('select * from verylargetable')     
request.pipe(new DataStream({maxParallel: 1}))  
                        // pipe to a new DataStream with no parallel processing
    .batch(64)
                        // optionally batch the requests that someone mentioned
    .consume(async (row) => write_to_other_database(row));
                        // flow control will be done automatically
```

Scramjet will use promises to control the flow. You can also try increasing the maxParallel method, but keep in mind that in this case the last line could start pushing rows simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

My own answer: instead of writing to the target database at the same time, I convert each row into an "insert" statement, and push the statement to a message queue ( RabbitMQ, a separate process ).  This is fast, and can keep-up with the rate of reading.  Another node process pulls from the queue ( more slowly ) and writes to the target database.  Thus the big "back-log" of rows is handled by the message queue itself, which is good at that sort of thing.